# Migrate Sharepoint AD import connection to Microsoft Identity Manager (MIM)

Tags: sharepoint-server, user-profile-service, mysite, user-profile-service-app, mim

We want to migrate Sharepoint user profile sychronization from active directory import to Microsoft Identity Manager (MIM).(Due to multiple AD forests requirement) 
Can we do this, and if we do this will users will have the same MySite site collection or create a new one.